# Read table with missing values and columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na, read.table

I m pretty new to R and need some help with a problem reading txt-documents.

As an example... I have the following data in txt

[image: txt-data]

```
20150505  8:30:00 ABC 15  550
20150504  4:40:00 ABC 15  500
20150503  2:34:00 .      3494
20140912 19:25:00 DEF 20  200
```

I need to read the data and separate it into different columns lets say A, B, C, D and E.

With the following code I get the warning that line 3 did not have 5 elements

```
  data <- read.table("data.txt", sep="", header=FALSE)
```

The other option just creates one column:

```
 data <- read.table("data.txt", sep="\t", header=FALSE)
```

With the next one I tried to fill the missing value in line 3, but got like 10 columns with most "NA" and data that should be in one column together, got separated:

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", sep ="", fill=TRUE)
```

Is there a another possibility to create the 5 needed columns, and the missing value just be a "NA"?
The real data I use has more than a million rows...

The main problem is, that I just don't find a way to read the data correctly.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to edit it as a text above.

Comment: `sep = ""` would indicate that every line element is in itself a column. `sep = "\t"` indicates a tab is used. It seems most sensible that `sep = "\t", fill = TRUE` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks you! I tried both options with `fill=TRUE` and it worked with `sep=""`. `sep="\t"` gave me only on column again.

Comment: If you already have the answer you may add it as an answer below. It may help future visitors of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with:

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", sep="", fill = TRUE, header=FALSE)
```

Now I got 5 columns and 4 rows. The empty value is filled with "NA".